# Axios error handling the err.response object

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux, axios

I have an React/Redux action creator which makes a post request on creation of a new user's account.

When I test the server validation I am expecting the `err.response` object inside the catch to be defined and return the validation error message. However, the `err.response` and `err.request` objects are not defined and I am getting the generic "An internal error occurred" when the user should be seeing the validation error instead.

I have followed the setup they recommended at https://github.com/axios/axios#handling-errors, however I've found no luck. Any idea?

```
import { REGISTER_SUCCESS, REGISTER_FAILED, RegisterReq, TokenRes } from "./types";
import { returnErrors } from "../errors/actions";
import { Config } from "../../utils/tokenConfig";
import axios, { AxiosResponse, AxiosError } from "axios";

export const registerUser = (user: RegisterReq) => (dispatch:Function):void => {
    const config: Config = {
        headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json"
        },
        withCredentials: false
    };

    axios.post<TokenRes>("/v1/users", user, config)
        .then((res: AxiosResponse<TokenRes>):void => dispatch({
            type: REGISTER_SUCCESS,
            payload: res.data
        }))
        .catch((err: AxiosError):void => {
            if(err.response) dispatch(returnErrors(err.response.data, err.response.status, REGISTER_FAILED));
            
            else if(err.request) dispatch(returnErrors(err.request.data, err.request.status, REGISTER_FAILED));
         
            dispatch(returnErrors("An internal error occurred", 500, REGISTER_FAILED));
        });
};
```

Comment: What the value of `err.message()`?

Comment: "Request failed with status code 400" which is the status code I defined the server to return upon an invalid input

Comment: What kind of response object you're creating from server in case error happens. As in I'm asking about the error DTO?

Comment: what is `console.log(err)`. I think this is because you need to define this in your endpoint

Comment: @Mohit I am using express-validator which returns `res.status(400).json(err.message)` where `err.message` is just a string

Comment: @RedBaron 

``` 
Error: Request failed with status code 400
    at createError (createError.js:16)
    at settle (settle.js:17)
    at XMLHttpRequest.handleLoad (xhr.js:61)
``` 
I'm looking at the type definition for an axios error and I'm not sure that would fix the problem https://github.com/axios/axios/blob/master/index.d.ts#L85-L92

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So it seems that the err properties are actually defined, but my component is rendering multiple times, which makes it return the generic error. This makes it look like the AxiosError properties are undefined. [image: Redux Devtools State Changes]

Inside the catch callback, just add an `else` to the final dispatch

```
.catch((err: AxiosError):void => {
    if(err.response) dispatch(returnErrors(err.response.data, err.response.status, REGISTER_FAILED));
            
    else if(err.request) dispatch(returnErrors(err.request.data, err.request.status, REGISTER_FAILED));
         
    else dispatch(returnErrors("An internal error occurred", 500, REGISTER_FAILED));
});
```